# Add URL before image name in PHP

Tags: php

When i store image name in table, want to store name like URL.

For example, I have ready URL like: http://192.168.137.1/NI/uploads/ that I want to add before image name.

I want this result: http://192.168.137.1/NI/uploads/imagename.png

PHP code:

```
//We will upload files to this folder
//So one thing don't forget, also create a folder named uploads inside your 
project folder i.e. MyApi folder
 define('UPLOAD_PATH', 'uploads/');

 //connecting to database 
 $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME) or die('Unable to 
 connect');

  //An array to display the response
  $response = array();

   //if the call is an api call 
   if(isset($_GET['apicall'])){

    //switching the api call 
    switch($_GET['apicall']){

    //if it is an upload call we will upload the image
    case 'uploadpic':

    //first confirming that we have the image and tags in the request 
    parameter
   if(isset($_FILES['pic']['name']) && isset($_POST['tags'])){

  //uploading file and storing it to database as well 
 try{
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_PATH . $_FILES['pic']
['name']);


 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO t_table (image,tags)
VALUES (?,?)");

 $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_FILES['pic']['name'],$_POST['tags']);
 if($stmt->execute()){
 $response['error'] = false;
 $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully';
 }else{
 throw new Exception("Could not upload file");
 }
 }catch(Exception $e){
 $response['error'] = true;
 $response['message'] = 'Could not upload file';
}

 }else{
 $response['error'] = true;
 $response['message'] = "Required params not available";
 }
```

Comment: Why? It will break when putting it live.

Comment: i think this is not usable

Comment: Whats that mean?

Comment: really dont know . i copyed this code . but i cleared fetching part from this code to show clearly my problem

Comment: Do not store url, just appending the base url of the project while showing it on UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not store URL, just append the `base url` of the project while showing it on UI. This won't work once you deploy the app on another IP or change the IP to a domain name.

Store the name and keep appending base url while iterating over the data on front-end.

Answer (score 0):

try this

public function url($patheFile, $imageName)
    {
        return sprintf(
            "%s://%s%s",
            isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http',
            $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
        );
    }
echo url('uplode', $_FILES['pic']['name'])

Comment: can you insert in my code?

Comment: you can use this in your code or use the function as function call
$image = sprintf("%s://%s%s",isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) &&$_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'https' : 'http',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '/uploads/' . $_FILES['pic']['name'])